# Change table in follow up reports

Tags: odoo-15, odoo-accounting

I need to change table that is generated in follow up report email - some basic styling and rearanging of columns.

[image]

I found [this solution](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/it-is-possible-to-inherit-account-report-invoice-document-and-replace-the-table-166806) to change "account.report_invoice_document" but I didn't find the same columns here as they are in report (from image) - missing Source Document, Communication.

This is Odoo v15 - can someone please guide me on how to modify this table.

Comment: We can't help you without knowing exactly what you are trying to achieve.
Also, `account.report_invoice_document` isn't trivial and I wouldn't recommend to modify it blindly.


If you just want to change the column order, you could probably use xml heritage: remove the column from where it is and add it back (you will have to hardcode back the column as there isn't any "move" feature in QWeb)
It works the same way than view inheritance:
<https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/tutorials/getting_started/13_inheritance.html#view-inheritance>

Comment: Yes - I'm avare that for changing column order I can remove column from where it is and add it back where I want. The problem Is that I can't find which document should be inherited (model) and don't know how to find it - I found few documents with similar information but not the same. Can you please let me know how it can be found in core files?

Comment: The xml is here:
https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/account/views/report_invoice.xml#L4
The python code here:
https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/16.0/addons/account/report/account_invoice_report.py

If you have a specific localisation, you might need to check in that localization if it doesn't override it to avoid conflicting and to be sure to have the right one.